# A trigonometric identity with given condition

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Let fix $\alpha,\theta\in [0,\pi]$, $\rho>1$, such that:
$$ \frac{\sin\theta}{(\rho^2-2\rho\cos\theta+1)^{1/2}}=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\rho}, $$
how i can prove that:
$$ \frac{\rho(\rho\cos\theta-1)(\rho-\cos\theta)}{(\rho^2-2\rho\cos\theta+1)^{3/2}}=
\frac{\cos\alpha(\rho^2-\sin^2\alpha)^{1/2}}{(\rho^2-\sin^2\alpha)^{1/2}-\cos\alpha} ? \tag{1}$$
I have no idea. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems strange. See here, lemma A.5 [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.06468.pdf)

Comment: Check out even simpler counterexample: $\rho=2,\sin\alpha =\sin\theta = \tfrac{\sqrt{15}}4,\cos\alpha =\cos\theta = \tfrac14$.

Comment: You have any idea on how i can derive (1)?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, i don't understand your hint.

Comment: Yes, there was a mistake in my question. But i can't go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a figure (writing "$p$" for "$\rho$") for acute $\theta$ and with $p\cos\theta\geq 1$, showing $\triangle OQR$ with
$$\theta := \angle ORQ, \qquad |OR|=1, \qquad  p := |QR|, \qquad q := |OQ|=\sqrt{p^2+1-2p\cos\theta} \tag{1}$$

[image]

Drop perpendiculars from $Q$ to $R'$ on $\overleftrightarrow{OR}$, and from $R$ to $Q'$ on $\overleftrightarrow{OQ}$; extend $\overline{QR'}$ and $\overline{Q'R}$ to meet at $P$, so that $O$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle PQR$. Necessarily, the perpendicular from $P$ to $P'$ on $\overline{QR}$ passes through $O$.

Defining $\alpha := \angle QOR'$ (see **Note** below), the problem's given information simply observes the two ways of expressing the length of $|QR'|$.
$$\frac{\sin\theta}{q} =\frac{\sin\alpha}{p} \quad\to\quad p\sin\theta = |QR'| = q \sin\alpha \tag2$$
Likewise, the elements of the target relation (note that I have multiplied-through  by $q$) have geometric counterparts:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{p(p\cos\theta-1)(p-\cos\theta)}{q^2}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{q\cos\alpha\sqrt{p^2-\sin^2\alpha}}{\sqrt{p^2-\sin^2\alpha}-\cos\alpha} &\quad\to\quad\frac{|QR||OR'||QP'|}{|QO|^2}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{|OR'||QQ'|}{|QQ'|-|OQ'|} \tag3 \\[6pt]
&\quad\to\quad\frac{|QR||OR'||QP'|}{|QO|^2}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{|OR'||QQ'|}{|QO|} \tag4 \\[6pt]
&\quad\to\quad\frac{|QP'|}{|QO|}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{|QQ'|}{|QR|} \tag5
\end{align}$$
We verify the relation by observing
$$\frac{|QP'|}{|QO|}=\cos\angle RQQ'=\frac{|QQ'|}{|QR|} \tag6$$

$\square$

---

**Note.** The above establishes the geometric heart of the desired equality. Non-acute $\theta$ and/or arbitrary $p$ require a bit of algebraic finesse to accommodate signed lengths and/or taking $\alpha$ to be the *supplement* of $\angle QOR'$. [g.kov's counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3865868/409) (which effectively asserts $\theta=\alpha$, so that $p=q$) reveals that such accommodations are required to make the relation hold in all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

> Given $\alpha,\theta\in[0,\pi]$, $\rho>1$, such that:
>
> \begin{align}\frac{\sin\theta}{(\rho^2-2\rho\cos\theta+1)^{1/2}}=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\rho}\tag{0}\label{0},\end{align}
>
> prove that:
>
> \begin{align}\frac{\rho(\rho\cos\theta-1)(\rho-\cos\theta)}{(\rho^2-2\rho\cos\theta+1)^{3/2}}&=\frac{\cos\alpha(\rho^2-\sin^2\alpha)^{1/2}}{(\rho^2-\sin^2\alpha)^{1/2}-\cos\alpha}\tag{1}\label{1}.\end{align}

**A counter example:**

\begin{align}
\text{Let }\quad \rho=2,\ \sin\alpha =\sin\theta = \tfrac{\sqrt{15}}4,\ \cos\alpha =\cos\theta = \tfrac14
.
\end{align}

Then equation \eqref{0} holds:
\begin{align}
\tfrac{\sqrt{15}}8&=\tfrac{\sqrt{15}}8
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}

but expression \eqref{1} evaluates to

\begin{align}
-\tfrac7{32}&= \tfrac7{24}
\tag{3}\label{3}
,
\end{align}

which is false.